# Csv from Kaggle puts all columns into 1 - how to separate with pd.read_csv and make usable df

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I just downloaded this CSV from kaggle

https://www.kaggle.com/psvishnu/bank-direct-marketing?select=bank-full.csv

However, when it downloads, all the 17 or so columns are in 1, so when I use

```
df = pd.read_csv('bank-full.csv)
```

it too has all values in one column.

Any thoughts would be great, I haven't come across this issue before, thanks!

df sample

```
58;"management";"married";"tertiary";"no";2143;"yes";"no";"unknown";5;"may";261;1;-1;0;"unknown";"no"
0     44;"technician";"single";"secondary";"no";29;"yes";"no";"unknown";5;"may";151;1;-1;0;"unknown";"no"
1   33;"entrepreneur";"married";"secondary";"no";2;"yes";"yes";"unknown";5;"may";76;1;-1;0;"unknown";"no"
2    47;"blue-collar";"married";"unknown";"no";1506;"yes";"no";"unknown";5;"may";92;1;-1;0;"unknown";"no"
3            33;"unknown";"single";"unknown";"no";1;"no";"no";"unknown";5;"may";198;1;-1;0;"unknown";"no"
4    35;"management";"married";"tertiary";"no";231;"yes";"no";"unknown";5;"may";139;1;-1;0;"unknown";"no"
5    28;"management";"single";"tertiary";"no";447;"yes";"yes";"unknown";5;"may";217;1;-1;0;"unknown";"no"
6  42;"entrepreneur";"divorced";"tertiary";"yes";2;"yes";"no";"unknown";5;"may";380;1;-1;0;"unknown";"no"
7         58;"retired";"married";"primary";"no";121;"yes";"no";"unknown";5;"may";50;1;-1;0;"unknown";"no"
8     43;"technician";"single";"secondary";"no";593;"yes";"no";"unknown";5;"may";55;1;-1;0;"unknown";"no"
9      41;"admin.";"divorced";"secondary";"no";270;"yes";"no";"unknown";5;"may";222;1;-1;0;"unknown";"no"
```

Comment: use `df = pd.read_csv('bank-full.csv',sep=';')` because the seprator is `;` and by default the seperator value is `,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv("<filename.csv>",sep=";") #Or you may use delimiter=";"
print(df)
```

Your file's columns are separated by `;` so we assigned separator as `;`.

You can get further more information about `read_csv` from [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: Magic! Thank you ! Yes set=";' was the key -- delimeter gave a keyerror.

Comment: Error?? What is it saying?

Comment: When sep is replaced with delimeter in the code above I received this -- TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'delimeter' -- but I see now it's a spelling error when see it's spelled 'delimiter' below

Comment: @Mr.J You typed wrong, `delimeter` is not wrong, it is `delimiter`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `delimiter` argument for `read_csv` function to set the character for separation as

```
df = pd.read_csv('bank-full.csv', delimiter=';')
```